# in MPI and C, how to send the the struct of struct information to slave processes and receive them?

Tags: c, struct, mpi

As shown in the codes, I have two structs in c. After some input reading and initialize_pop (parent_pop),parent_pop that contains 4 individuals generated.Then I have to send each individual to each process (4 processes) to evaluate and generate new individual on each process (totally still 4 individuals), and then receive these 4 new individuals in the master process to form a new population called child_pop.This is my psudo-program. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct{
double *xreal;
int **gene;
double crowd_dist;
}
individual;

typedef struct
{
individual *ind;
}
population;



Here is the main program:
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
population *parent_pop;
int i, my_id, num_procs;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
// Find out process ID and process number //
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
input_read();/*read input*/
initialize_pop (parent_pop);/*generate 4 individuals to form the parent_pop*/
MPI_Datatype MPI_individual;
int count = 3;
int blocklens[] = { 1, 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint disps[3];
MPI_Datatype old_types[] = { MPI_int, MPI_double, MPI_double };
disps[0] = offsetof(individual, *xreal);
disps[1] = offsetof(individual, **gene);
disps[2] = offsetof(individual, crowd_dist);
MPI_Type_struct(count, blocklens, disps, old_types, &MPI_individual);
MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_individual);

*********Part need help****************************
send each individual to each process;
*********Part need help****************************

evaluate(parent_pop);/*evaluate each individual in each process*/
genearte_new_pop(child_pop);/*generate 4 new individuals to form the child_pop*/

*********Part need help****************************
receive each individual information from the slave processes to get the child_pop in the master process
*********Part need help****************************

}
```

Comment: I see several things wrong: (1) sending `int **gene` will not be straightforward because when this memory is allocated, it will not be contiguous - only each row will be contiguous in memory. (2) your types do not match up with your `individual` struct itself. It should be `{MPI_double, MPI_int, MPI_double}`. (3) your counts are incorrect because they must reflect the actual number of elements in your arrays `xreal` and `gene` (which must again be contiguous for the datatype to be correct). To answer your actual question: a `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` using this datatype should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am an programming beginner. If possible would you please elaborate more about these (1) I have to use **gene due to other functions in this program, then how should I send **gene? (2) Doesn't the count is the number of blocks of elements the derived type? Should it be equal to the size of the array of blocklens? (3) Thanks for your answer again!

Comment: (1) When you first allocate your `gene` array, you must allocate it in contiguous memory (usually done by making a 1D array). If you really want to keep the rest of your program the same, then initially allocate `geneTemp` as 1D, and set each pointer for your 2D array `gene` to correspond to the memory locations of your 1D array `geneTemp`. Not pretty, but it means you won't have to change any other part of your program. (2) Yes, the counts to send via MPI should be the size of the arrays.

Comment: Thanks! If possible would please show me the basic codes to do the allocation for geneTemp and gene. In addition, how about *xreal, how to transfer the array that this pointer points to other process?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I've decided to make an official answer to your question because there's too much going on in the comments for others to follow.

The three main things I see that you need to do are (there might be more):

1. Allocate `int **gene` contiguously in memory so as to be able to send it via MPI in one go.
2. Ensure that the types you declare for `oldtypes` matches the types in order for your `individual` struct.
3. Ensure your counts properly reflect the actual number of elements in your arrays (which should probably all be contiguous to make this as painless as possible on you).

Once you have set up your `MPI_individual` properly, you should be able to send an individual with a simple `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` pair using `MPI_individual` as the type.

To expand upon these points:

1. In C, when you have a pointer to pointers (like `int **gene`), you initially allocate memory for `nRow` pointers to integers in memory for each row. Elements of this initial `malloc` (`gene[iRow]`, an `int *` variable) are all contiguous in memory. Note that what these elements end up actually pointing to might not be contiguous; in fact, they almost assuredly are NOT. Then, when you allocate memory for each row element (the `int *`, accessible by `gene[iRow]`, you allocate `nCol` integers in memory that are contiguous. Again note that while each row is contiguous, row `iRow` and `iRow+1` might not be allocated directly after each other. In C++, `new` and `new*` work exactly the same way.

To get around this problem, I would suggest you make a temporary variable, say `geneTemp` that will be how you allocate the memory itself.

```
int *geneTemp;
geneTemp = (int *)malloc(nRow*nCol*sizeof(int));
```

Now that you have a single contiguous block of memory (nRow*nCol integers), you can point your original `int **gene` to the correct spots in this memory block, using something like:

```
int **gene;
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < nRow; ++iRow) {
    gene[iRow] = &geneTemp[iRow*nCol + 0];
}
```

I'll admit it's not pretty, but this setup allows you to re-use all of your old code, but now the 2D array `gene` is pointing to a single contiguous block of integers.

2. This is an easy fix. It should simply be:

   ```
   MPI_Datatype old_types[] = {MPI_double, MPI_int, MPI_double};
   ```

   to match your `individual` struct.
3. Now when you setup your `MPI_individual` type, you have to actually send the values in each array. Sending pointers is meaningless because each MPI process has different memory spaces. What is in address `55` in process 0 is completely separate from what is in address `55` in process 1.

To send actual data, not pointers:

```
int blocklens[3] = { nReals, nRows*nCols, 1 };
MPI_Aint disps[3];
disps[0] = offsetof(individual, xreal[0]);
disps[1] = offsetof(individual, gene[0][0]);
disps[2] = offsetof(individual, crowd_dist);
```

(Something like this at least... I don't know what `offsetof()` is, but this is how I think it should be used here. I have not tested this code.)

I hope this more clearly explains how the memory is setup, and in particular how it should be setup for an MPI derived datatype.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. Still a little problem is, since every size in the individual struct is different now (gene is nrow*ncol, xreal is nreal), how should I decide the count in the MPI_Type_struct ? Thanks again!

Comment: n addition, I have tested the code, offsetof is to find the address. It seems that offsetof(individual, xreal[0]) would cause error. Looking for solutions.

Comment: Are you saying that each struct has a different nrow/ncol? Then yes, you'll have a problem: you cannot create a MPI datatype that is constantly changing sizes. I think you'll unfortunately have to simply babysit it everytime you want to send a struct by sending over the first array, then the second, then the int, and reconstructing the struct on the other side...

Comment: As to the `offset()` function, if it takes in a pointer, give it the pointer to the first `int` or `double` in the array. If it takes a value, then the above should work.

Comment: I cannot get the offset () right. Do I need to allocate memory for the pointers first?

Comment: @DezhiZhou yes. Otherwise where is the pointer going to be pointing to in memory?